# WebHost failed to process a request error of Silverlight App

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, iis-8

I have got 4.5 Silverlight & RiaServices app under IIS 8.
It starts fine but is impossible to login.
All possible MS Windows features are enabled.

**Error of Silverlight app:**

```
load operation failed for query 'login'
```

**Fidller gives error 500**

**Error in MS Windows Events with source System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0 :**

WebHost failed to process a request.
 Sender Information: System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment+HostingManager/45653674
 Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/Polaris/Services/Polaris-RIAServicesLibraryMain-Web-PolarisAuthenticationDomainService.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.Type> System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.get_ComplexTypes()'.. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1 System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.DomainServiceDescription.get_ComplexTypes()'.
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.RegisterSurrogates(ContractDescription contractDesc, DomainServiceDescription domainServiceDescription)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ServiceUtility.LoadContractDescription(ContractDescription contractDesc, DomainServiceDescription domainServiceDescription)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory.CreateContract(DomainServiceDescription description)
   at Microsoft.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.SoapXmlEndpointFactory.CreateEndpoints(DomainServiceDescription description, DomainServiceHost serviceHost)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost.CreateDescription(IDictionary`2& implementedContracts)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.InitializeDescription(UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost.InitializeDescription(Type serviceType, UriSchemeKeyedCollection baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHost..ctor(Type domainServiceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.DomainServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(Type serviceType, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
   at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.EnsureServiceAvailableFast(String relativeVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity)
 Process Name: w3wp
 Process ID: 3512

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that MS Windows 2012 has installed old version of RIA Services so I just installed a RIA Services SP2 and it works now!